# Change Android screen resolution programmatically?

Tags: android

I run custom IPTV application. To update my application, I use default android intent after downloading new file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This produces default application update screen.

[image]

The problem is that on the very small TV's (PAL), buttons "CANCEL" and "INSTALL" aren't even visible, and people are unable to update the app since they can't see the buttons. Can I somehow change width/height or resolution of screen when updating? Or can you suggest any other solution?

Comment: Did you try NOMone Resolution Changer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I somehow change width/height or resolution of screen when updating?

No.

> Or can you suggest any other solution?

This sounds like a bug in the installer app, as it should be able to handle any screen resolution. If this is your own AOSP build, fix it there. If you got Android on this hardware from the manufacturer, point out the bug and see if they will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What does your layout file look light? Have you given equal weight to the buttons in your layout? You might also try android:scaleType="fitXY" or measure the screen width and height from the Window Service and scale accordingly.